# checking if a point is already in a vector/list -- performance

Tags: c++, performance

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264760/efficient-way-of-finding-distance-between-two-3d-points)

I have a vector of points that will, for instance, store 100K+ points.

```
std::vector<Point> point_vec;
```

I want to check if a position (x, y, z) to be added is already in `point_vec` (represented by an instance of `class Point` ). The following function will check this (in a `for` loop)

```
bool samePoints(const Point& p1, 
                const double x1, 
                const double y1, 
                const double z1) {

     return fabs(p1.x - x1) < EPSILON &&
            fabs(p1.y - y1) < EPSILON &&
            fabs(p1.z - z1) < EPSILON;
}
```

But, I guess checking if `x in list/ vector` will be a costly operation. I want to know if there is a better way to check if a) Points are equal (perhaps an operator "=" on class Point??  and (b)  Is there some other , better data structure than `vector' that I should make use of.  OR if there is an operation on vector that will speed up checking for 'same points'

For (b) please note that I need to std::sort these points as well. So any other data structure that you may suggest should be able to sort these points.

**UPDATE**

I want the points in the sorted state only. It is just that vector doesn't sort those (so I need to perform a sort operation. Should I use `std::set<Point> point_set` instead of instead of `std::vector <Point> point_vec` ?  IF SO: Is adding each point to a set a costly operation ? Or 'vector' sorting that I do in the end turns out costlier overall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the collection of points always sorted or must it sometimes be in an unsorted state? If the former, a std:;set of points will be fast to determine if a point is already there, and will maintain the points in sorted order. You would have to supply a suitable ordering function (not an equality one), which may be faster than your equality test.

Comment: @Neil: hi!  The collection of points is *not* in the sorted state from the beginning..But, finally, I do want all points to be 'sorted' Thus, I don't really need 'unsorted' points. so do you recomment using `std::set <Point> point_set`  instead of `std::vector <Point> point_vec`  in the first place?

Comment: @memC If sorting and lookup speed is the most important thing yes. but sets don't support other operations, such as random access using op[] that you may need. An alternative is to maintain the vector in sorted order and to use binary search to check if a particular point is there.

Comment: @Neil: sorry but what did you mean by a 'suitable ordering function'?

Comment: @memC You need to provide the equivalent of operator <() for your point class (or in fact provide operator<()) - it should return true if one point is in a sense less than another one, false otherwise.

Comment: @Neil: I see. Thank you. BTW, if I am to use vector and if I just need to find out minimum value of the 3D point, is there something in STL similar to `min_element(vec.begin(), vec.end())` that will allow me to pass a functor as a 3rd argument (like done for `std::sort` ??

Comment: @memC The std::find_if algorithm does this, but it will simply perform  a linear search. If you have sorted your vector, you could use std::binary_search or std::equal_range. But obviously, if you have sorted, the min element will be the first :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that while Niel and Vlad have the right idea, they've left out a particularly important detail: *You can't sensibly order N-dimensional points with a 1-dimensional comparator if you want to be correct only to within epsilon instead of exactly correct.*

Patrick is on target with quad/oct-trees, but not with hashing--hashing implicitly requires a mapping where all items close in 3D must be mapped close in 1D (along the hash), which is provably impossible.

So, assuming that you can start with a set sorted linearly using a comparator like

`x1<x2 || (x1==x2 && (y1<y2 || (y1==y2 && z1<z2))`

here's what you need to do:

- Take your vector and subtract epsilon along every dimension.  Do a binary search for the index of that element (if any).  Call that `i0`
- Take your vector and add epsilon along every dimension.  Do a binary search for that index.  Call that `i1`
- Search everything between `i0` and `i1` linearly to see if any of those are actually within epsilon of your vector in *every* dimension (not just in the 1D sort direction).

If your points are randomly distributed, this will tend to be faster than constructing an oct-tree.  If your points tend to fall along lines (e.g. x1==x2, y1==y2 for many z), then this scheme will often pick out huge chunks of the list as indistinguishable using a linear sort, and you should instead use an oct-tree for fast searching.

Answer (score 0):

`std::set` sorts the items internally. You would only need to supply compare function.

Answer (score 0):

An STL set or hash_set might help.
Building up the structure will be slower than building up a vector or list, but looking up points will be much faster.

Alternatively, you could also use a quad-tree or octo-tree.

Comment: Note: hash_set will only work if your points have integer coordinates.

Comment: @Neil, I actually meant sets and hash_sets, not maps (I was a bit too fast on this).